# Sonar Ant 4.4.1 not launching - IllegalStateException

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I use 
Sonar Qube - 4.4.1
JDK Version 1.7
Sonar Ant Task version: 2.1  - I was able to launch my sonar server successfully and when I try to execute my build.xml with ant, I"m getting below error - could someone help please:

```
sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
[sonar:sonar] Sonar Ant Task version: 2.1
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/D:/NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME/sonar-ant-task-   2.1.jar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Default locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Work directory: D:\ATG9.1\DWInt\CoreCommerce\.sonar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Sonar Server 4.4.1

 BUILD FAILED
 D:\NEW_SONARQUBE_HOME\buildCoreCommerce.xml:28:   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  Fail to download libraries from server
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars35.dowloadFiles(Jars35.java:79)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.Jars35.download(Jars35.java:58)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download35(JarDownloader.java:56)

    at org.sonar.runner.impl.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:40)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:57)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:71)
```

Comment: I'm guessing there was originally a URL in that error message. Can you get from your build machine to that URL?